# On Amazon, how do I set specific text notification message number for each shipping address?

Tags: amazon

Currently I have two shipping addresses, how do I set specific text notification message number for each of these addresses? I do have paid for Amazon Prime, so I don't want to open another account simply for this reason.

Comment: Did you click the link? (**DON'T CROSS POST**)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I've flagged it to move to web application. There is no way to reply to you without cross posting.